# Property 'length' does not exists on type 'ITravel'. TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, react-typescript

I'm not able to figure out how to cast the array in the json object i get from axios.get response. I keep getting the **property 'length' does not exist on type ''. TS2339 error. How to get rid of this error? json contract is as below . I have skipped some code and put only the relevant parts.

```
   {
    "someStuff":{
         "items":[
                   {
                     "id":1
                   },
                   {
                     "id":2
                   }
                 ]
        }
   }
```

ITravel.tsx

```
   export interface ISomeStuff{
   }

   export interface IItems{
   id:number;
   }

   export interface ITravel extends ISomeInterface{
   items: IItems[];
   }
```

Route.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import FormLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FormLabel';
import { ITravel } from './ITravel.tsx';

  type Props = {
    iTravel: ITravel;
  }

 const Route = (props: Props) => {
       const { items } = props.iTravel;
       

     return(
          <FormLabel>
            <strong>{items.length}</strong>
          </FormLabel>
     );
 }
```

Comment: You have a typo in `import { Itravel }`. It should be `ITravel`. If you fix that does that change anything? Because otherwise your code seems to work fine: https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSkAPSWOYAOxiSk3STgEkOmQBnOAN6k4IugBMAXHHoBXEACNmAblIBfclRrwGTFm04AVKCgBuSADaDho4D15SudgNoBdFetIwAnmHYAFHDB+AF4rUTojUwsHSLNzd3I0CHpeeAAxaBAAGRRFcylkdBgAOjSAYThQgAoBNAALYHMxInpVAEpKgD44AB5O2oamltUegHpOxOTUxAgZJkq4KrBA+zgAiCCO4O6hcKSU+AE6OzhVBeWN3mLgWIsVcNFycKIYGSh6KusH3oyobNyLBNvt8eqkcPQAOb9WxIPjFcxISEwOojUZg5JQr4PMa-f55IHhNr3VRAA

Comment: Hi Alex, i fixed that typo and it is not issue. I still am getting that error

Answer (score 0):

With only being able to see the code you've pasted, my two thoughts go to:

1. Your import within Route.tsx that you're including the .tsx within the import of ITravel (probably not likely though).
2. Have you ensured that you've correctly accessed the array within the JSON? i.e based off what you've pasted that it's not: items.someStuff.items.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Basically i need to "save" ITravel.tsx whenever i make changes in it before compiling Route.tsx. Not sure if this is a thing with vscode. I'm new to react. In visual studio i don't remember doing this after every changes.